# Recompile Vim for pythoncomplete#Complete on modules *other* than standard library?

Tags: python, vim

I like using `pythoncomplete#Complete` for [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) `omnicompletion`, but it doesn't work for Python modules other than the standard library.

Is there a way to re-compile Vim so that this will work on non-standard library modules?

I have tried `pysmell`, et. al., but they just don't work as well as  `pythoncomplete#Complete`. This is for a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting PYTHONPATH prior to starting Vim?

You can also modify the path from inside Vim, by doing:

```
:python import sys
:python print sys.path
:python sys.path.append(...)
... etc
```

Comment: what I didn't realize is that vim will complete on packages that are loaded into the currently edited file. If they are not imported, they will not be completed.